# How to read "Builder Number" from "About Phone" settings in android?

Tags: android

I'm trying to read which ROM the user is using from my app.

It seems that this info can be seen in the phone's settings, in the About Phone setting under "Build Number".

How can I read this info with code?

Couldn't see it with `android.os.Build class`..

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oops, found it.
it's in android.os.Build.DISPLAY